# How to derive a decoder semiautomatically for a list of some type with Circe?

Tags: scala, circe

I have an implicit class that decodes server's response into a JSON and latter in the right case class to avoid repeating calls to `.as` and `.getOrElse` all around the tests:

```scala
implicit class RouteTestResultBody(testResult: RouteTestResult) {
  def body: String = bodyOf(testResult)
  def decodedBody[T](implicit d: Decoder[T]): T =
    decode[Json](body)
      .fold(err => throw new Exception(s"Body is not a valid JSON: $body"), identity)
      .as[T]
      .getOrElse(throw new Exception(s"JSON doesn't have the right shape: $body"))
}
```

Of course, it relies on us passing a decoder:

```scala
import io.circe.generic.semiauto.deriveDecoder

val result: RouteTestResult = ...
result.decodedBody(deriveDecoder[SomeType[AnotherType])
```

It works most of the time, but fails when the response is a list:

```scala
result.dedoceBody(deriveDecoder[List[SomeType]])
// throws "JSON doesn't have the right shape"
```

How can I semiautomatically derive a decoder for a list with specific types inside?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The terminology here is unfortunately overloaded, in that we use "deriving" in two senses:

- Providing an instance for e.g. `List[A]` given an instance for `A`.
- Providing an instance for a case class or sealed trait hierarchy given instances for all member types.

This problem isn't specific to Circe, or even Scala. In writing about Circe I generally try to avoid referring to the first kind of instance generation as "derivation" at all, and to refer to the second kind as "generic derivation" to emphasize that we're generating instances via a generic representation of the algebraic data type.

The fact that we sometimes use the same word to refer to both kinds of type class instance generation is a problem because they're typically very distinct mechanisms in Scala. In Circe the thing that provides an encoder or decoder instance for `List[A]` given one for `A` is a method in the type class companion object. For example, in the `object Decoder` in circe-core we have a method like this:

```scala
implicit def decodeList[A](implicit decodeA: Decoder[A]): Decoder[List[A]] = ...
```

Because this method definition is in the `Decoder` companion object, if you ask for an implicit `Decoder[List[A]]` in a context where you have an implicit `Decoder[A]`, the compiler will find and use `decodeList`. You don't need any imports or extra definitions. For example:

```
scala> case class Foo(i: Int)
class Foo

scala> import io.circe.Decoder, io.circe.parser
import io.circe.Decoder
import io.circe.parser

scala> implicit val decodeFoo: Decoder[Foo] = Decoder[Int].map(Foo(_))
val decodeFoo: io.circe.Decoder[Foo] = io.circe.Decoder$$anon$1@6e992c05

scala> parser.decode[List[Foo]]("[1, 2, 3]")
val res0: Either[io.circe.Error,List[Foo]] = Right(List(Foo(1), Foo(2), Foo(3)))
```

If we desugared the implicit machinery here, it would look like this:

```
scala> parser.decode[List[Foo]]("[1, 2, 3]")(Decoder.decodeList(decodeFoo))
val res1: Either[io.circe.Error,List[Foo]] = Right(List(Foo(1), Foo(2), Foo(3)))
```

Note that we *could* replace first kind of derivation with the second, and it would still compile:

```
scala> import io.circe.generic.semiauto.deriveDecoder
import io.circe.generic.semiauto.deriveDecoder

scala> parser.decode[List[Foo]]("[1, 2, 3]")(deriveDecoder[List[Foo]])
val res2: Either[io.circe.Error,List[Foo]] = Left(DecodingFailure(CNil, List()))
```

This compiles because Scala's `List` is an algebraic data type that has a generic representation that circe-generic can create an instance for. The decoding fails for this input, though, since this representation doesn't result in the encoding we expect. We can derive the corresponding encoder to see what this encoding looks like:

```
scala> import io.circe.Encoder, io.circe.generic.semiauto.deriveEncoder
import io.circe.Encoder
import io.circe.generic.semiauto.deriveEncoder

scala> implicit val encodeFoo: Encoder[Foo] = Encoder[Int].contramap(_.i)
val encodeFoo: io.circe.Encoder[Foo] = io.circe.Encoder$$anon$1@2717857a

scala> deriveEncoder[List[Foo]].apply(List(Foo(1), Foo(2)))
val res3: io.circe.Json =
{
  "::" : [
    1,
    2
  ]
}
```

So we're actually seeing the `::` case class for `List`, which is basically never what we want.

If you need to provide a `Decoder[List[Foo]]` explicitly, the solution is to use either the `Decoder.apply` "summoner" method, or to call `Decoder.decodeList` explicitly:

```
scala> Decoder[List[Foo]]
val res4: io.circe.Decoder[List[Foo]] = io.circe.Decoder$$anon$44@5d40f590

scala> Decoder.decodeList[Foo]
val res5: io.circe.Decoder[List[Foo]] = io.circe.Decoder$$anon$44@2f936a01

scala> Decoder.decodeList(decodeFoo)
val res6: io.circe.Decoder[List[Foo]] = io.circe.Decoder$$anon$44@7f525e05
```

These all provide exactly the same instance, and which you should choose is a matter of taste.

---

As a footnote, I've thought about special-casing `List` in circe-generic so that `deriveDecoder[List[X]]` doesn't compile, since it's approximately never what you want (but seems like it might be, especially because of the confusing way we talk about instance derivation). I typically don't like the idea of having special cases like that, but I think in this case it might be the right thing to do, since this question comes up a lot.